# How to retrieve records based on column name using cursors

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am rekha and I am working data base. I am a fresher from past 2 months only I am working on sql server.

I have a query that is I have 2 tables.for example businesstype table contains id,businesstype and location based on location I will retrieve the data.that's fine.and second table is like employee and columns are id,name and businesstype.so my question is for each businesstype I will get the records from the employee table ultimately as below:

1,sathish,softwar
4,pushpa,Software
2,ramesh,Electronics
4,rajesh,Electronics

I solve this one by using joins,operators and subquery also.but I need the solution to this query by using cursors.

I wrote like the following ways:

1) SELECT ID, Name , BusinessType  FROM Employee 
                  WHERE BusinessType in (select BusinessType from Employee)
order by BusinessType desc

2)select ID,Name,BusinessType
from Employee where exists (select BusinessType from Employee)

3)select @Location = Location from @BusinessTypeTemp

select ID
      ,BusinessType
      ,Location 
       from BusinessType where Location=@Location

```
DECLARE @TempEmployeeInfo varchar(500)
DECLARE @pos        int,
         @nextpos    int,
        @nextRecpos int, 
        @valuelen   int
```

/* creating temp table to insert address types*/

```
CREATE TABLE  #EmployeeInfo (BusinessType nvarchar(80) )
SELECT  @TempEmployeeInfo =   BusinessType FROM @EmployeeTemp
```

/* Code for checking  separator is ',' and save into temp table */

```
SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1


WHILE @nextpos > 0
BEGIN


  SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @TempEmployeeInfo, @pos + 1)
  SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                          THEN @nextpos
                          ELSE len(@TempEmployeeInfo) + 1
                     END - @pos - 1
INSERT #EmployeeInfo(BusinessType)  VALUES (convert(nvarchar, substring(@TempEmployeeInfo, @pos+1, @valuelen)))
  SELECT @pos = @nextpos
END




    SELECT @Count = count(BusinessType) from Employee WHERE BusinessType IN (SELECT BusinessType FROM #EmployeeInfo)
        PRINT @count


    IF(@Count<>0)
        BEGIN


            select ID,Name,BusinessType from Employee

            WHERE BusinessType IN (SELECT BusinessType FROM #EmployeeInfo)
            order by BusinessType desc


       END
    ELSE
         BEGIN
         SELECT 0 as ReturnID
         END
```

But they don't want this, they want the result by using only cursors.and also I want to display the both table results in a single SP.

So please anyone help me. Please send the replies urgent because today is my last day to solve this.

Rekha

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to do your work for you.  If you are having trouble with a specific piece of code, feel free to show us the code with what you've tried and ask for help with a specific question.